# Are modules bimodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm thinking on the following question:
If $A$ is a commutative ring, $M$ is $A$-module if and only if $M$ is $(A,A)$-bimodule?

I know that $M$ is and module-$A$ because $A$ is commutative, but is the question true?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where are you havin problems checking if this is so or not?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if it is true. Is it?

Comment: But if you try to prove it, what happeens?

Comment: Which specific part of the definition are you having trouble confirming / disproving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define the right $A$-module multiplication on $M$ as the left-module structure, i.e. $$ ma := am, \qquad m \in M, a \in A $$
then this is in fact a right $A$-module structure, due to $A$'s commutativity, we have 
$$ (ma)b = b(am) = (ba)m = (ab)m = m(ab) $$

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check that every left $A$-module is in an obvious way a right $A^{\textrm{op}}$-module, where $A^{\textrm{op}}$ is the same ring as $A$ except multiplication $\cdot$ in $A^{\textrm{op}}$ is defined in the opposite way: $a \cdot b$ is defined as $ba$.

If $A$ is commutative, then $A = A^{\textrm{op}}$, so every left $A$-module is also a right $A$-module.